# How to easily add Django urls?

Tags: django, web

I am working on a website, very basic, just HTML and CSS. Its all static and I'm needing to add more urls. I have read the Django documentation and it isnt quite clicking with me.

What I have is my home page and I need to be able to click the link on my navbar and be taken to the next page. I'm just not sure how to add another URL in django.

Thank you in advance! Sorry if I missed anything. It's my first post

Comment: Can you post your current Django code?

Comment: Why are you using Django for a static website?

Comment: Not everything is going to be static. This is just for the beginnning and I would like to learn Django for the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `yoursite/urls.py` you can add as many urls as you need. As you can see there is list of urls in urlpatterns. When you building website with just html and css then word 'pattern' does not make any sense, and you can think about these 'patterns' just as links to your pages.

Now, when you need to add new links you can simply append them to this urlpatterns list. For example, your site is xyz.com, and you want user to go to xyz.com/page1, your html link looks like `<a href="www.xyz.com/page1">Link to page 1</a>` then you need to add such url to urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^page1/', views.page1)
```

which simply means to use function page1 from views.py

And I fully agree with @Anshul, for such task its better not to use frameworks like django, because you do not use any advantages over just creating static website.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go along and add the default page that they see when they visit my site. What is the code I should add to my views.py?

Comment: it is a bit hard to write code snipet in comments, but lets say user goes to xyz.com/ , url will look like:  `url(r'^$', views.home)` , also you already created your html page for this url - home.html, then your home-view will look like here: [home_view](https://pastebin.com/uLPtAnbT)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a urls.py file and add urlpatterns to create multiple urls.
Each URL will need to be connected to a method in your views.py for it to work.

This link will help you understand what you need
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/

Note - If your website is totally static and will remain static, I would suggest not using Django at all and just creating a static website using HTML, CSS which will make it easier to maintain and give you a larger number of cheaper hosting options.